# Proof that there isn't a $c$-additive approximation to Partition Problem

Tags: np-complete, approximation, partitions

Define
Partition to consist of all tuples $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ which can be divided to two groups in which the sums of the two groups are equal.

Is there a proof that there isn't an additive approximation algorithm to the problem?
Where $c$ is the minimal distance between the groups.

Comment: You can reduce Partition to your problem. Give it a shot!

Comment: The idea is that given an instance $x$ of Partition, you can produce an instance $y$ of Partition such that (1) if $x$ is a Yes instance then so is $y$, (2) if $x$ is a No instance then every partition of $y$ results in two parts whose distance is more than $c$. Try to understand why this implies that there is (probably) no $c$-additive approximation algorithm to Partition.

Comment: @yellowcard123 The question is for "some c" or for "all c"?